# Modifiers not visible under objects from services

Tags: perl, moo, bread-board

Given the following:

- Moo 2.001001;
- Bread::Board 0.34;
- a `Bread::Board` container
- base class `Foo` with property `str` and `around` modifier for `str`
- subclass `Bar` extending `Foo`

The issue:

- [GOOD] when instantiating object from plain `Bar`, `Foo::str` modifier is executed;
- [BAD] when instantiating object from container service for `Bar`, `Foo::str` modifier is not executed;
- [WORSE] after [BAD] happens, instantiating from plain `Bar` no longer works either;

Code example:

```
#!/usr/qlc/apps/common/perl_5.18.2/bin/perl -w

package Foo;

use Moo;

has str => ( is => 'rw', default => '' );

sub BUILD {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

    $self->str($self->str);
}

around str => sub {
    my ($orig, $self, $val) = @_;

    return $self->$orig unless defined $val;

    $self->$orig('prefix_'.$val);
};
# end of Foo



package Bar;

use Moo;

extends 'Foo';
# end of Bar



package main;

use 5.010;
use strictures 2;

use Bread::Board;

my $c = container 'MyApp' => as {
    service 'foo' => ( class => 'Foo', parameters => { str => { optional => 1 } } );
    service 'bar' => ( class => 'Bar', parameters => { str => { optional => 1 } } );
};


my $foo_plain = Foo->new({ str => 'foo_plain' });
say "foo_plain = ".$foo_plain->str;

my $foo_bb = $c->resolve( service => 'foo', parameters => { str => 'foo_bb' } );
say "foo_bb = ".$foo_bb->str;

$foo_bb->str('foo_bb_setter');
say "foo_bb_setter = ".$foo_bb->str;

my $foo_plain_after_bb = Foo->new({ str => 'foo_plain_after_bb' });
say "foo_plain_after_bb = ".$foo_plain_after_bb->str;


my $bar_plain = Bar->new({ str => 'bar_plain' });
say "bar_plain = ".$bar_plain->str;

my $bar_bb = $c->resolve( service => 'bar', parameters => { str => 'bar_bb' } );
say "bar_bb = ".$bar_bb->str;

$bar_bb->str('bar_bb_setter');
say "bar_bb_setter = ".$bar_bb->str;

my $bar_plain_after_bb = Bar->new({ str => 'bar_plain_after_bb' });
say "bar_plain_after_bb = ".$bar_plain_after_bb->str;


die;
```

Output:

```
foo_plain = prefix_foo_plain
foo_bb = prefix_foo_bb
foo_bb_setter = prefix_foo_bb_setter
foo_plain_after_bb = prefix_foo_plain_after_bb
bar_plain = prefix_bar_plain
bar_bb = bar_bb
bar_bb_setter = bar_bb_setter
bar_plain_after_bb = bar_plain_after_bb
```

Please note outputs `bar_bb`, `bar_bb_setter` and `bar_plain_after_bb` do not contain `prefix_` string.

Why?

Comment: Issue is being investigated at https://github.com/stevan/BreadBoard/issues/61

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in Bread::Board.

Fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/stevan/BreadBoard/commit/dc8970ff2a8f1b08460b44b4c2a8f006787cceb6).

Thanks [@Yanick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10356/yanick).